# Why the last sentence of append,isn't shown at web?

Tags: mysql, go, visual-studio-code, go-echo

Actually my last sentence of database(mysql table) after append does not show in web which I create with Echo framework.

I have question on line 39: Comment item doesn't scan and show on local host:1324.

```
package main

    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"

        _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
        "github.com/labstack/echo"
    )

    type datatype struct {
        SiteID          string `sql: "Site_ID"`
        Scope           string `sql: "Scope"`
        Region          string `sql: "Region"`
        Province        string `sql: "Province"`
        Vendor          string `sql: "Vendor"`
        Supervisor      string `sql: "Supervisor"`
        SOAC_Date       string `sql: "SOAC_Date"`
        Last_Visit_Date string `sql: "Last_Visit_Date"`
        Number_of_Visit string `sql: "Number_of_Visit"`
        COC_Date        string `sql: "COC_Date"`
        FAT_Date        string `sql: "FAT_Date"`
        FAC_Date        string `sql: "FAC_Date"`
        Comment         string `sql: "Comment"`
    }

    func pegy(c echo.Context) error {
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Abc@12345@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "Error while connecting to DB!")
        }
        defer db.Close()
        row, _ := db.Query("select Site_ID,Scope,region,province,vendor,supervisor,SOAC_Date,Last_Visit_Date,number_of_visit,COC_Date,FAT_Date,FAC_Date,Comment from test.db")
        var res []string
        for row.Next() {
            var db datatype
            row.Scan(&db.SiteID, &db.Scope, &db.Region, &db.Province, &db.Vendor, &db.Supervisor, &db.SOAC_Date, &db.Last_Visit_Date, &db.Number_of_Visit, &db.COC_Date, &db.FAT_Date, &db.FAC_Date, &db.Comment)
            res = append(res, fmt.Sprintf("Site_Id: %s |Scope: %s|Region: %s |Province: %s|Vendor: %s |Supervisor: %s |SOAC_Date: %s|Last_Visit_date: %s|Number_of_Visit :%s|COC_Date: %s|FAT_Date: %s|FAC_Date: %s|Comment: %s", db.SiteID, db.Scope, db.Region, db.Province, db.Vendor, db.Supervisor, db.SOAC_Date, db.Last_Visit_Date, db.Number_of_Visit, db.COC_Date, db.FAT_Date, db.FAC_Date, db.Comment))
        }
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, res)
    }

    func main() {
        e := echo.New() //By Shayan
        e.GET("/", pegy)
        e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1324"))
    }
```

Comment: Don't ignore the errors returned by Query, Scan, and [Rows.Err](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Err)